# Why is ssh-keygen creating blank .pub files?

Tags: linux, ssh, terminal, ssh-keys

A few months back I used `ssh-keygen` to create `id_rsa` / `id_rsa.pub` for use with Github and everything went fine. (I am using OSX Sierra, 10.12.6 locally, but I'm generating the keypairs on a linux terminal that I remote into. I don't know the exact flavor of linux.)

I need a new keypair for a different repository, so I repeated the process and created `id_rsa_2` / `id_rsa_2.pub`. Everything seemed to go fine, but when I actually try to get my public key, I get nothing.

So if I enter

```
cat ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub
```

Then I get the output just as I expect.

But if I enter

```
cat ~/.ssh/id_rsa_2.pub
```

Then I get nothing back at all. The terminal just advances to the next line without any output. I have now generated `id_rsa_2`, `id_rsa_3`, `id_rsa_4`, and even `id_rsa_5`. In every case, `ssh-keygen` appears to run without a hitch and gives all expected output during the creation process. I can see the `id_rsa_n` and `id_rsa_n.pub` files exactly where I expect them to be. (Where n in {2, 3, 4, 5}).

But whenever I try to retrieve the public key, I get nothing.

The only thing I've found via Google is a possibility of being out of space. However, I have confirmed that I'm only using a couple of megs of my user space (and I have a lot more than that available to me). So it's not a space issue. So... why is `ssh-keygen` giving me blank .pub files?

The exact command I'm running is:

```
ssh-keygen -t rsa -C "my email address"
```

Comment: You did the `cat` just after the `ssh-keygen`? From the same directory? Try by using the `-f` switch to force the filename to be whatever you want. Add `-v` to have ssh-keygen be more verbose.

Comment: I reran with:

`ssh-keygen -t rsa -C "nathaniel.givens@gmail.com" -f ida_rsa_6 -v`

I didn't get any additional output from ssh-keygen. It just said "Generating public private rsa key pair." Then asked for a passphrase. I left that blank. Then "Your identification has been saved in ida_rsa_6" and "Your public key has been saved in ida_rsa_6.pub". It then gave me the key fingerprint and the key's randomart image.

Comment: After that, I ran `cat ida_rsa_6.pub` . I got the same result as before: no output at all from the console. It just incremented to the next console line.

Comment: I am running these commands within my `.ssh` folder. I can `ls` and see the files there. I have no idea why they won't output anything.

Comment: I also tried viewing the files with `nano` . The first one I generated months ago, `id_rsa.pub` looks as expected: I can see my public key. Everything that I've generated on Friday and today is just a blank, empty file.

Comment: A bruteforce method would be to prefix your command with `strace -e open`; it will then show you all files that `ssh-keygen` opens for both read or write, so it should show you the filenames. But when doing `ls -l` you see the file you need with a nonzero size? It is only `cat` that bugs? Any chance it is an alias or something? run `alias` to see or use `/bin/cat` instead of just cat

Comment: And your filesystem is not in readonly mode? You can write other files at the same spot? `echo 1 > foobar ; cat foobar` displays 1 ?

Comment: Yeah, I do have write permissions. The `echo` command you gave me works fine and displays 1 as the response when I run it in the .ssh directory. I'll look at your bruteforce method now.

Comment: So I'm pretty sure it's not a problem with `cat` in particular. I can open the old id_rsa.pub file with nano and see the contents. When I open any of the new .pub files (I have generated 6 so far) with nano, they are empty. When I run `ls -l` they all show as having 0 bytes. I'm confused, because ssh-keygen is definitely creating the files and it's not throwing any errors at all (even with the `-v` flag), so I don't know why the files it's creating are all empty.

Comment: Replace `-e open` by `-e write` to see all write calls. The result, a number, is the number of bytes written per call, or an error.

Comment: Are you really 100% definitively sure there is enough space available on the disk? If you try the command with user root (which has different quotas + reserved space typically in a filesystem) does it work? If you search for all questions with the same query, at the end all solutions came down to the fact that the filesystem was full... For example: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42703981/id-rsa-pub-is-empty-when-created-by-ssh-keygen-t-rsa

Comment: So, I'm really embarrassed, but you're right. They lowered the cap to something like 40MB of space in my home directory, and that was the issue after all.

I really appreciate the help. Sorry to waste peoples' time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This turned out to be another case where the problem was lack of space. Because there was no space left in my home directory, ssh-keygen could only output empty files. Once I cleared some space, it worked  just fine.